# Linux image (.img) file compatibility between dd,partclone,partimage and clonezilla

Tags: linux

In Linux , is the image (.img) file compatible between dd ,partclone ,partimage and clonezilla.Actually i want use the partclone to create a image from a partition,and restore it to another partition using dd or dcfldd.Is it possible , because partclone mentioned as it is a special image format. Thanks.

Comment: Under linux, a dot and some subsequent characters in the name of a file has no defined meaning.  If `partclone` makes an image and calls it `foo.img` or `bar.exe` or `baz.wtf` it is irrelevant to what the file actually contains.

Answer (score 1):

I would venture to say no even without looking through their documentation and source code. At least not directly.

I do know that Clonezilla uses compression on their images, which I think they just pipe the output of dd through gzip.

Answer (score 1):

".img" is not standardized. dd copies each bit exactly as it is to the file you create. according to their [website](http://partclone.org/index.php) partclone doesn't do that:

> Partclone provides utilities to back up and restore **used-blocks** of a partition **...**

i'm not 100% sure but i doubt that this works.

Answer (score 1):

From the [partclone dev repository's Trac page](http://partclone.nchc.org.tw/):

> Partclone provides utilities to back up and restore used-blocks of a partition and it is designed for higher compatibility of the file system by using existing library, e.g. **e2fslibs is used to read and write the ext2 partition**.

I added an emphasis to the important part.  It appears that `partclone` reads the files on the filesystem as files, and then adds them to an image.

In contrast, `dd` works by reading the disk or partition as a block device, *bit by bit*, and makes an exact copy of exactly what each bit is on the entire disk or partition.  This means that `dd` picks up filesystem bits, the contents of unused sectors, and so on.

<strike>As such, it appears that `dd` would expect far more information than is provided in a `partclone` image file.</strike>

As such, it appears that writing an image using `dd` would require in the image the presence of far more information than is provided in a `partclone` image file.

In conclusion: `dd` cannot be used to write images made by `partclone` no matter what.

Comment: technically, `dd` doesn't expect any info at all -- it's just copying bits from place to place...